# Generating (n) buttons at runtime

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm in a situation were I have a button for each action in my app. The number of actions available I only receive from the server at run time. So I need to generate the buttons based on that at run time and attach them to the view.

What is the best approach to do this?

1. Creating a Layout with maximum number of actions I might get back. Set all visibility to `GONE`, and at run time change the visibility to `VISIBLE`, OR
2. Creating a factory class which takes the number of actions and returns a view containing all buttons with their listeners and then attach it to my view
3. Other suggestions??

I'm asking to know which approach is better for performance since the buttons are to be generated inside a `RecyclerView` and the list might contain several items.

Comment: I tihink option 2 is the best approach

Comment: @maheryhaja the second option is the best but most complex to implement. I'm using an expandable view as list elements. So the buttons should be only shown when the element has been expanded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not using the `RecyclerView` mechanism?

`RecyclerView` knows how to handle this kind of structure...
It generateing a `view` just for the objects that showing on the screen, and when another pops in, it replacing it with an old one...

don't tangle your self.

Comment: Actually, this is a very simple, yet effective idea which I didn't have in mind. Thank you!